# Firebase Realtime Database is not generating dynamic Id for Imported Data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Realtime Database is not generating dynamic Id for Imported Data via json file but it generates id for data posted via frontend... using POST request. Like cartItemess object has dynamically generated id - "MOsH2-zPBHMM06f1dNI", but the below init data i imported manually using Import option which never generated any id.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's expected.  If you're using the import function in the Firebase console, it will simply import all the data exactly as it appears in the JSON file.  It doesn't generate any extra data or do any manipulation of it.  This is different than the POST calls to the REST API or calls to `push()` in client SDKs, which will generate a random ID.